# django how to perform checks on other records during isertion

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django model:

```
class BarEvent(models.Model):
    EVENT_TYPES = ( ('op', 'opening'), ('cl', 'closing'), ('ea', 'event_a'), ('eb','event_b')   )

    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BAR_BALANCE_TYPES)
    date = models.DateField("Data", default=datetime.now)
```

where BarEvent objects represent events sorted by date and time. 
I need to make sure that 'opening' or 'closing' events are alternated (i.e. there are not two consecutive 'opening' or 'closing' events), so if I try to insert a 'opening' event after another 'opening' event the insertion is prevented but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Should I implement a check on existing records in a overridden save method?

Comment: The model you have mentioned does not have any `closing_date` field?

Comment: Each record is a separate event with its own datetime, 
so the table could be:


'op' - 01/01/2012 00:00
'a1' - 02/01/2012 00:00
'cl' - 03/01/2012 00:00
'op' - 03/01/2012 12:00

but must not be:

'op' - 01/01/2012 00:00
'a1' - 02/01/2012 00:00
'op' - 03/01/2012 00:00

as there are two consecutive 'op' events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `clean` method in model to check for extra validations before actually saving an object.

```
class BarEvent(models.Model):
    EVENT_TYPES = ( ('op', 'opening'), ('cl', 'closing'), ('ea', 'event_a'), ('eb','event_b')   )

    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BAR_BALANCE_TYPES)
    date = models.DateField("Data", default=datetime.now)

    def clean(self):
        """
            Custom clean method to validate there can not be two
            consecutive events of same type
        """

        if self.objects.latest('date').event_type == self.event_type:
            raise ValidationError('Consecutive events of same type %s' % self.event_type)
```

Comment: @user1924809 It is just an example how to perform checks on other records during insertion. Please add your own validation logics. Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did read about clean method but thought it could be used only for a field validation in a single records regardless of existing records values. I will try that!